# angular 4 - Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Tags: angular, http, preflight

I have angular 4 project in local and i want use api to get information , i get this error

```
localhost/:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:????. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
```

I have jquery project in local that call same api and get answer with no error

What is problem ? I see many question and answer in this site and nobody can help me.

Comment: It's a CORS issue. The server doesn't respond with the expected headers to the preflight request and therefore the browser refuses to make the actual request. Is your jquery project loaded from the same URL and port as where you make the request and the Angular project from a different URL or port?

Comment: i run them in localhost , and in same url , but  nothing change

Answer (score 0):

This is very much the case of `CORS` as mentioned by Gunter. If you are requesting a resource that is on a different domain(as in your case i.e. api's domain) from the domain that you are requesting, then you get such errors.

When performing certain types of cross-domain Ajax requests, modern browsers that support CORS will insert an extra "preflight" request to determine whether they have permission to perform the action.

Please refer to this link: [Cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: what i must to do ?

Comment: You can set `preflight` response on your api side. You can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841786/response-for-preflight-is-invalid-redirect-error?rq=1 as well.

Comment: in angular 4 , i use $.ajax and dont user angular http , error is gone !!!

Comment: now you're mixing jquery and angular way of doing things which is not recommended. proper angular project should have no dependency on jquery